# google api in ipad

Tags: ipad

I am trying to load google map to uiwebview after performing a query using "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=test,test,50786".The problem is that i need to hide the side bar and top address bar from the resulting map page and show only the map area in the map view .Is this possible?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.We only need to set the output mode parameter to get the map area only i.e

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=test,test,50786&output=embed will return only the map area.

Thanks :)